# How to store a value in a list only if its value is higher than the value of any of the list's current elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im new here, so forgive me if Im not clear, but I'll do my best...

Im new to python, so this may be a newbie question:

I have to insert numbers until a negative one is read, after that, I should print the 5 highest numbers that were read by the machine. The catch is that I cant have more than 6 numbers stored at a time.

I wrote the following:

```
while numb >= 0:
numb = int(input()) 

if numb >= 0:
    numbList.append(numb)          
else:
    break                          

numbList.sort()
```

But the `.append` command will only make my list larger, something I dont want.

Could you lend me a hand?

Im also not a native speaker, so please forgive any mistakes I might have made :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import deque

all_numbers = deque(maxlen=6)
while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number < 0:
        break
    if not all_numbers or number > all_numbers[-1]:
        all_numbers.append(number)
    # print(all_numbers)

print(list(all_numbers)[-5:])
```

Console:

```
Enter a positive number: 1
Enter a positive number: 2
Enter a positive number: 3
Enter a positive number: 4
Enter a positive number: 5
Enter a positive number: 6
Enter a positive number: 7
Enter a positive number: 8
Enter a positive number: 9
Enter a positive number: -1
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: @MatheusPorto Glad to help!